# Spring Framework apllication-profile.properties doesn't set property value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file, application.properties

This is my application.properties file

```
spring.profiles.active=de
username=postgres
password=12345
dburl=localhost:postgre
```

This is application-de.properties file

```
username=**** postgres
password=****12345
dburl=localhost:****de
```

This is @Configuration class

```
@Value("${username}")
String username;

@Value("${password}")
String password;

@Value("${dburl}")
String dburl;



@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer property(){
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new 
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}


@Bean
FakeDataSource fakeDataSource(){
    FakeDataSource fakeDataSource = new FakeDataSource();
    fakeDataSource.setUsername(username);
    fakeDataSource.setPassword(password);
    fakeDataSource.setDburl(dburl);
    return fakeDataSource;
}
```

This is main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Spring5DiDemoDiAssignmentApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Spring5DiDemoDiAssignmentApplication.class, 
    args);

    FakeDataSource fakeDataSource = (FakeDataSource) ctx.getBean(FakeDataSource.class);
    System.out.println(fakeDataSource.getUsername()+" "+fakeDataSource.getPassword()+" 
    "+fakeDataSource.getDburl());
```

This is output

```
User ****12345 localhost:****de
```

All properties set but username doesn't set. If I change apllication-de.properties as below

```
 name=**** postgres
 password=****12345
 dburl=localhost:****de
```

and @Configuration class

```
@Value("${name}")
String username;
```

The output

```
**** postgres ****12345 localhost:****de
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `username` property is already defined by default in your `environmentProperties` and is being resolved by the `PropertySourcesPropertyResolver`, so that's why you are not able to inject the value that you need.

In order to avoid such issues, the common practice is to add the prefix to your custom properties.

So, your `application.properties` and `application-de.properties` should contain something like

```
app.username=**** postgres
app.password=****12345
app.dburl=localhost:****de
```

and then your `@Configuration` file should look contain:

```
@Value("${app.username}")
String username;

@Value("${app.password}")
String password;

@Value("${app.dburl}")
String dburl;
```

This way you should avoid collisions with any default properties.

Be aware that `app` prefix is only an example and you can replace it with whatever name you wish, you can also chain prefixes like `my.app.prop.username` if you wish.